# bundle install rails "sh.exe has stopped working" on Windows 7

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, windows-7, bundler

I install railsinstaller packg which includes

```
Ruby 1.8.7-p334
Rails 3.0.7
Git 1.7.3.1
Sqlite 3.7.3
TinyTDS 0.4.5
SQL Server support 3.0.14
DevKit
bundler 1.0.15
```

I clone my project through GitHub and so far everything is fine.

Next I did 'bundle install' in my application which gave errors on gems which i fetch through ':git => ...'

```
Error is "sh.exe has stopped working."
```

is there any solution for it?